# Exploit RSA , given some information about n

Tags: rsa, public-key

> Every week Bob updates his public RSA modulus $n=p*q$ and encryption
>   exponent $e$ by picking a new pair of primes $p$ and $q$ and a new exponent
>   $e$. After several weeks, bob becomes lazy and decides to keep the prime
>   $p$ fixed and only updates the other prime $q$ every week. Eve hears about
>   this. How can she exploit this information to decrypt messages sent to
>   Bob using his public key ?

I don't know how to solve it, any help or hint would be much appreciated.
I understand we need to retrieve $p$ and then we can get any $q_i$, and from there decipher the messages, but how can we do that ? okay so $n_1 = pq_1, n_2 = pq_2 , n_3 =pq_3$ , so on ... How do we get $p$

Comment: For a real-life analysis of this phenomenon, see https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.conference.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question spezifies $n_1 = p*q_1$, $n_2 = p*q_2$. With that we can calculate $gcd(n_1,n_2) = p$ which lets us solve $n_1 / p = q_1$ and $n_2 / p = q_1$. Now we have every information needed to calculate the private part of Bob's key and thereby decrypt all messages sent to him.